# How to replace value with Another Row value in SAS from Data Set

Tags: sas, sas-macro

How to replace if the value is 1 with the below row value **"Weight"** find the below image current data set and the final output required,

please any one help how to get the final required dataset

[image: dataset image]

Comment: Please post data as text.  Also you seem to have stuffed two separate datasets into your input photograph. One with the employee data and a separate one with the variable weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat that extra row as a separate dataset. Let's do it in multiple steps to make it clearer.

```
data weights;
  set have;
  where emp_id='weight';
  rename test1-test4 = weight1-weight4 ;
  keep test1-test4 ;
run;
data want ;
  if _n_=1 then set weights;
  set have;
  array t test1-test4;
  array w weight1-weight4;
  if emp_id = 'weight' then delete;
  do index=1 to dim(t);
     t[index]=t[index]*w[index];
  end;
  drop weight1-weight4;
run;
```

If you want to mess up your results by keeping the weight observation you could change the IF THEN logic so that the values of T[*] are only updated when the observation is real employee data but the weight observation is not deleted.

```
  if emp_id ne 'weight' then do index=1 to dim(t);
     t[index]=t[index]*w[index];
  end;
```

You could do this without creating the separate dataset if you want, but not sure it really helps.

Comment: if the columns are fixed the above code works fine. if the names of the columns are different not as test test1 and all.. how to modify the code ..

Comment: Just update the names in the ARRAY,RENAME,and DROP statements.  If the names do not lend themselves to simple numeric suffixed variable list then the RENAME statement will need to list each old=new pair.

Answer (score 0):

I have split the above data set into two data sets for employee_id and employee weight

```
data two;
retain type 'n';
input GROUP $ CODE $;
fmtname=cats(trim(group)||'f');
start=1; 
label=code;
cards;
TEST1 1.412
TEST2 0.207
TEST3 0.207
TEST4 0.207

proc format cntlin=two;
run;

data one;
input emp_id TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4;
format test1 test1f. test2 test2f. test3 test3f. test4 test4f.;
cards;
10850 0 1 0 1
10851 1 0 0 0
10852 0 0 1 0
10853 0 0 0 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Exact ouput of the above, Without spliting the data sets

```
data have;
input id $ test1-test4;
cards;
1 0 0 0 1
2 1 0 0 0
3 0 0 1 0
4 0 0 0 0
weight 1.412 0.207 0.207 0.207;
data want;
set have;
if _n_=1 then set have(keep=test1-test4 
rename=(test1-test4=t1-t4)) point=nobs nobs=nobs;
array x{*} test1-test4;
array y{*} t1-t4;
do i=1 to dim(x);
if x{i} then x{i}=y{i};
end;
drop i t1-t4;
run;
```